# How to do national insurance number regular expression in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is my Regular Expression                                                               `^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}[A-Z]{1}?$`

I am using this expression in `angularjs`   `ng-pattern-restrict` . I can't type anything in the input field.

If i am use `^[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{0,6}[A-Z]{0,1}?$` : this expression then i can type three letters but can't type number.

If i will type two letters then only i can type six numbers.If i type three letters then i can't type numbers

I need The result like this: `PP123456P` Expression.

Can Anyone Help me

Answer (score 0):

```
 ^[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{1,6}[A-Z]{1}?$
```

Should work, the reason you could type 3 letters is that the second group was allowed to be size 0-6 and then when you put in 3 letters it has matched the first 2 letter group, the  numeric group with a 0 length match and finally the last Alpha. by changing it to 1-6 you force the entry to be between 1 and 6 numbers.

Comment: Now I Cant type anything, please help me to fix

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a bit of redundancy in your regular expression and not quite sure what you were trying to do with `[A-Z]{1}?`, is this supposed to be an optional letter?

Although simplistic compared with the actual validation rules of National Insurance numbers you could use

```
^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}[A-Z]$
```

Breaking that down...

- `^` Must match at the start of the string
- `[A-Z]{2}` Exactly 2 letters in the range A-Z
- `[0-9][6]` Exactly 6 digits in the range 0-9
- `[A-Z]` Exactly 1 letter in the range A-Z
- `$` There must be nothing else following the previous matches